# Creatiing an iso file

Tags: iso

I am trying to convert an iso image so that I can use a usb stick to install ubuntu on my laptop. When I go to startup disk creator and click other the ubuntu iso file has no bytes so I cannot create a file to install ubuntu why?

Comment: What?  If the iso file is zero bytes then you failed to download it.  You don't create the file, you download it and the startup disk creator copies it to a flash drive.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? Can you explain what you're trying to do and why?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create a Live USB for Ubuntu, use [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) instead. Easy to use, either download from internet and create, or create from a local ISO file.

Otherwise, you can use `dd` to do the same thing. For example `sudo dd if=/path/to/Ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=8M`.

Comment: This is *possibly* a Mac system, as that's the only situation where the ISO has to be converted to another form before being written to a USB stick, to make it bootable. USB flash drives written with UNetbootin are not bootabble on Macs (even with the Mac version of UNetbootin, as the documentation states). Similarly, on a Mac, `dd`ing the ISO image won't create something bootable (on Macs) either. Of course, this might not be a Mac...the author of this question has not (or not yet) provided many details to help us figure out the nature of the problem.

Comment: unetbootin has a OS X version anyway. For Mac OS X users, they may need to use Disk Utility.app to create USB Live. `dd` is available anyway...

Comment: Like I said, the OS X version of UNetbootin doesn't create media that will boot on Macs. [*Microsoft Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7, or Linux, or Mac OS X 10.5+. Note that resulting USB drives are bootable only on PCs (not on Macs).*](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: As a Linux user, I am not aware the issue on OS X. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

First plug-in the usb device and run the following command

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This will give you list of all the partitions you have. Check the partitions carefully. Most probably /dev/sdb is the usb one(if no other usb storage is plugged-in).You should see something like this(if it is a 8 GB pendrive)

Disk /dev/sdb: 8.0 GB,blabla.....

Now to make a bootable usb

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/filename.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

BE CAREFUL with of option. If you carelessly put something wrong you will be doomed.